# IF Function in Microsoft EXCEL not executing well

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have the following spreadsheet in EXCEL (in French) where I'm using the IF function to fill the cell **I8** with the following:

- IF the cell **I7** is blank then fill it with blank **""**
- IF the cell **I7** is not blank and the cell **I10** has the side "**SHORT**" then calculate **I6-I7**
- IF the cell **I7** is not blank and the cell **I10** has the side "**LONG**" then calculate **I7-I6**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJUrY.png)

The goal is to calculate how much points between our entry and exit prices while respecting the side of the trade. I attached an image of the sheet.

I tired this formula (Si is same as IF) but it didn't work:
=SI(ESTVIDE(I7),"",SI(I10="Long",I7-I6,SI(I10="Short",I6-I7,"")))

Comment: Try changing `I10="Short"` to `H10="SHORT"`. Similarly for Long.

Comment: I can't believe that I missed that. It worked, thank you so much

Comment: It's because they're merged cells. The data is stored in the top left cell reference of the merged cells.

Comment: if you only have "short" and "long" as the choices you can reduce it to so: =SI(ESTVIDE(I7),"",SI(I10="Long",I7-I6,I6-I7))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Based on the image, the cell filled in short/long you actually check is H10 rather then I10, since the mergered cells only keep data shown on the top left. Accordingly, change your original function I10="short/long" to H10="short/long"

-If it is not mergered cells, you function is going to work.